# Is it a bad practice to store JWT tokens in database?

Tags: jwt, authorization

To implement a logout function, i stored JWT tokens in database.

When the user logs out, i just delete the token from the database and if there is no token in the database, i fire an unauthorized response.

Is this a bad practice or a necessity to implement this function?

I also want to implement an ip confirmation so the JWT is only valid if it comes from the ip address, so i will just add an ip column next to JWT column and also check ip...

Even if my JWT tokens are cracked, since i store them in database, an attacker cannot login my system. The system looks like to me more powerfull this way.

What is your experience and knowledge about this?

Comment: JWTs are generally misunderstood and vastly overused. If you can store it in a database and look it up every time, you could more than likely just use a plain old session id, which would be more robust, more secure and a lot simpler. JWTs do have their place, but using them as an authentication token in every request (or in other words, to maintain a user session) is not what they are for in general. (Special cases and exceptions do apply though, I'm not at all saying JWTs are useless.)

Comment: Great comment @GaborLengyel - you should consider making this a proper answer ;)

Comment: Well a problem arises when you want to immediately invalidate an access token that was valid a few moments ago and had a longer expiration time. You may want to immediatley invalidate in matters like: you may be having a **logout from all devices** feature in your application which when clicked deletes all tokens from a user's record in DB. To achieve such a feature you will most likely have to store token in DB so that when  a DB lookup fails, the token is declared invalid by the server.